# I have a game that has scores and i want to save them to a txt file in order of top 5

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I want to save my scores to a text file but have only the top 5 scores show so lets say in my text file i have 23,20,16,15,10 and i get a score of 13
it will replace 10 with 13 so i will have 23,20,16,15,13 .

I have tried doing this but i cant find a way to keep the scores from the previous game so i just keep deleting everything and replacing it with new scores.its really annoying

```py
scores = [(name1, score1), (name2, score2)]

with open('scores.txt', 'w') as f:

    for username, score in scores:

        f.write('Username: {0}, Score: {1}\n'.format(username, score))
```

Answer (score 0):

First you write all you scores into a text file. (Use `a` for append mode and `+` for and reading)

```py
with open('scores.txt', 'a+') as file:
  for score in scores:
    file.write(f'{score}\n')
```

Then retrive your scores

```py
with open('scores.txt') as file:
  scores = [int(i) for i in file.readlines()]
  top_five = sorted(scores, reverse=True)[:5]
```

`top_five` will have the top five scores

Comment: You will have to sort the scores too